# How do you make inputs non case sensitive in vb?

Tags: vb.net

I’m new to programming and I want to know if there is an easier way to make inputs on vb non case sensitive with if statements. 
Currently I would have to do something like this:

```
If example = “exam” then...
Elseif example = “Exam” then...
Elseif example = “EXam” then...
```

I feel this takes too long and is highly inefficient.

Is there any way I could just make it non case sensitive so as long as the correct spelling of a word is inputted, it would not matter if it contains higher or lower case letters?

Comment: I would suggest example.toUpper() or example.toLower()

Answer (score 3):

You can use [String.Equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.equals?view=netframework-4.8)

```vb
If example.Equals("exam", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) Then ...
```